# ¿Por qué tengo dos toolbars en mi app?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, toolbar

Os comento.

Este es un proyecto en Xamarin forms que fui desarrollando poco a poco.
Tengo una Master Page y el proyecto Main se inicia con la misma. El caso es que en esa primera pantalla (probando la app en Android) me aparecen 2 Toolbar una debajo de la otra, una de ellas la que Android crea a través del atributo ToolbarResource y otra que es la creada en la parte compartida del código, la cual pertenece a mi Master Page.

He intentado de mil formas hacer que la Toolbar que crea Android desaparezca en esta **primera pantalla** (ya que en las siguientes pantallas no me aparece la Toolbar del Master) y ninguna de las soluciones me funciona.

¿Alguna idea? Os dejo una captura de como se ve esta Toolbar en la pantalla inicial por si os sirve de guía:

[[image: Imagen de las 2 Toolbars1]

Como siempre, cualquier dato que necesitéis a más os lo puedo proporcionar sin problema.

> **P.D.** Si ya me ayudáis a cambiarle el color a la barra de arriba del todo os hago un monumento. Muchas gracias.

### EDITADO

Probé a cambiarlo tanto en mi MainActivity como en mi AndroidManifest y el error que me da es que no encuentra el recurso. Adjunto el código que tengo en styles.xml, imagino que tendré que cambiar algo en ese archivo:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/sexcondites_splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
<!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
<!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
<!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

<!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>-->
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Como lo has intentado quitar?

Basta con poner la siguiente linea de codigo en el `OnCreate()` de tu clase.

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
```

En tu caso creo que seria el `MainActivity.cs` pero recuerda que lo puedes poner en todas las clases donde quieras eliminar la barra superior.
Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {            
                RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);            
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te escribo abajo lo que me ha pasado.

Comment: @Diego prueba ahora. Con eso debería ser mas que suficiente. Me dejas saber, saludos.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Es probable que el fallo esté en que no tengo en mi proyecto el Layout Main. Diría que el layout se setea en mi MainPage con la línea:
Content = customMap;
De nuevo muchísimas gracias por el esfuerzo.

Answer (score 0):

puede que te falte inhabilitar la barra desde el archivo appshell.
puedes probar con esta linea Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

https://youtu.be/mvnMtCE5x5o

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/350236)